# Not sure how to interpret D3 API

Tags: d3.js

I'm trying to learn how to correctly read the D3 API and am confused how to interpret some of the items. I'm looking at the csv api.

```
 d3.csv(url[[, accessor], callback])
```

While there are plenty of examples on the web I still don't know exactly what some of this means.

To get to the point what does [, accessor] mean? In examples I usually see the filename of the csv. Is that all this is?

Additionally why are the brackets structured surrounding the callback word as so?

```
 [[, accessor, callback]
```

[D3 CSV API](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/CSV)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `accessor` parameter is an optional function to pre-process the rows of the CSV file, look [here](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/CSV#parse) for description. The square bracket notation means that something is optional and can be omitted. Nested square brackets mean that there is an optional part within an optional. In particular,

```
d3.csv(url[[, accessor], callback])
```

means that

```
d3.csv(url),
d3.csv(url, callback),
d3.csv(url, accessor, callback)
```

are all legal, while all other combinations like

```
d3.csv(url, accessor)
```

are not.

Comment: This may be a more basic javascript question but how does javascript know that the callback can be either the second or third argument in d3.csv?

Comment: If function is called with two arguments, then callback is the second one; if there are three, it's the third. JS always knows the actual number of arguments passed.